# I'd like to know which is the C++ Standard draft number corresponding to the link below

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

http://eel.is/c++draft/

The reason why I'm asking this is because the section §9.5.1 [class.union.anon] in N4582 (which appears to be the latest draft) corresponds to the section [§9.3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union.anon) in the link above. I have always thought that these two versions of the standard should coincide, or maybe this is just an editorial error.

Comment: Section tags (like [class.union.anon]) stay the same even if section numbers change.

Comment: @PeteBecker But isn't there a possibility of an error in this case?

Comment: @JohnKalane: It's always possible. Thanks for checking! Though in future such questions would be better addressed to the relevant mailing list. It's hard to see how this question will be particularly useful to future SO visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4582 is the latest "*published*" draft. It represents the state of the document on the day it was released, including any substantive wording changes proposed and accepted in conference, but editorial changes are made all the time — in this case, rather a lot of them.

Eelis is presenting you with the current-ish, bleeding-edge-ish state of the standard source as found in version control. If you follow his link to the Github repository, you'll see that there were many, many, many commits between N4582's March publication and Eelis's 7th April source pull, including [one resulting in the section numbering change you've identified](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/04798c768c124dfed38056137e3fc67a9b9a8ba8).

Modulo further changes, you can expect to see the new section numbering for this paragraph in whatever the next working draft ends up being.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not familiar with the site https://github.com/Eelis/draft. Is there any place in there where I could get instructions on how to use it?

Comment: For example, how could I find the commit that changed the section number that I referred to above?

Comment: @JohnKalane: It's fairly simple as websites go, so just have a look around. But if you really need them, GitHub has help guides: https://guides.github.com/

Comment: I'll try the help guide. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnKalane The particular commit at issue is https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/04798c768c124dfed38056137e3fc67a9b9a8ba8

Comment: @T.C.: Good find! I debated having a little hunt, but realised I couldn't be arsed ;)

Comment: Slight nitpick: N4582 should incorporate all the "decisions made at conference" (those not rejected by the editor, at least); the later commits are editorial polishing - lots of it.

Comment: @T.C. Granted. I'm not too familiar with the typewriting process as it pertains to ISO WGs. I've adjusted my explanation a bit.